# How to design disjoint triangular corner on top side of a div

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I design this triangular corner marked with yellow color on top side of the inside div?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have made the inside div only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a triangle then position that by `position: absolute`. more explanation in code:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 12px solid #aaa;
}

.triangle-left {
  width: 0; /* this five code lines for making a triangle */
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid white;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute; /* this three code line for positioning of triangle */
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="triangle-left"></div>
```

See this for how making a triangle: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_shapes_triangle-left

Answer (score 1):

try this one!
anything you want is here,
but first try to make a container then copy the code!  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_shapes_triangle-left